# Online Computer Science articles repository?

Tags: computer-science

When I need some complex algorithm I first check if there's anything relevant already published on the Internet. 10 times out of 10 I'll find that someone already have figured out a solution much smarter than what I would have thought of.

Apart from a generic Google search, I use:

- **[Citeseer](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/)**  That has a lot of good theoric reports from Universities
- **[Dr Dobb's Portal](http://www.ddj.com)** More practical than Citeseer but very often too specific to a particular technology or language
- **[Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/)** Even more theoretic contains draft and pre-prints (just in case I'm desperate :) )

I've also found the **[J.UCS](http://www.jucs.org/)** (Journal of Universal Computer Science) containing some interesting articles (but i've not really used any of the info I found there).

Do you know of any other place where good CS articles can be searched and read for free?

Comment: One way of looking at it, is that people in the research community have educational/academic accounts to those libraries (IEEE, ACM). So the only people paying for articles are industry people like you and me, who do not contribute otherwise to the field. I'd say that's fair.

Comment: No, is not fair at all: irrespectively of the fact that much of that research is paid by us, tax payers, restricting access to knowledge is alien to the spirit of true science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google’s [CS Curriculum Search](http://code.google.com/edu/curriculumsearch/) might be useful. It's a Google web search restricted to the CS departments of universities.  It categorises the results into “Lectures”, “Assignments” and “Reference”.

Also [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/), which is like Wikipedia but with standards.

Answer (score 4):

If you find something on ACM that is behind the pay wall, you can usually find it for free on one of the authors' websites or in the Citeseer cache. Also, a lot of CS articles are published by Springer and may only show up on [their web site](http://springerlink.com/computer-science/) (behind a pay wall).

[DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/) is useful if you want to look at a particular author or conference. Their links to papers are to the "official" for-pay versions, though.

BTW, individual membership dues for the ACM [aren't too onerous](http://www.acm.org/membership/dues) and entitle you to access to their library. IIRC, they also offer group health insurance to members, which may be helpful if you're self-employed.

Answer (score 3):

I check http://mathworld.wolfram.com for math-y stuff.

If you're a full member of the ACM, articles are [generally] free: which could easily make the cost of the membership worthwhile to you (or your employer).

Comment: Thanks Warren. I was looking for something more CS oriented but wolfram site is a resource worthy to be my bookmark :)

Comment: Access to the ACM's Digital Library is a separate subscription on top of your annual membership fee.  Membership is $99 and Digital Library access is another $99.

Comment: If you're into computer sciencey stuff (and rich), then the ACM Digital Library it totally worth it. I'm always printing PDFs to read when away from the computer.

Comment: Note that if you don't have the Digital Library option, you still get on-line access to articles from the ful lhistory of any particular journals to which you're subscribed.

Answer (score 3):

Google Scholar.

Outside of that, I'm not sure. Most profs will have PDFs of their articles somewhere on their university home page, so you can look up people who've done research and get some articles there.

Comment: Thanks Vlion. The problem with Google Scholar is that it tends to direct you to ACM, IEE, Springer and other places where articles are not free ...

Comment: If there is a mirror PDF, you can look next to the title hyperlink and see a domain where you can get the doc for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually consult paper (and sometimes electronic) copies of journals and conference proceedings at university libraries (on site).

You can find field-specific resources as well. For instance, in computer vision, there's a lot of knowledge at http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/

Answer (score 1):

There is a good search engine I`m using it: http://www.readbook.ir It can help you to find ISI, IEEE and ACM and... papers separately. try it

Answer (score 0):

There are fantastic mathematical libraries around for which you pay modest cost and get the *whole* library, in executable form, already ported to your platform. NAG - Numerical Algorithms Group, is by far the best well known, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Research might have some interesting articles as well. [Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/)